# How to return an offset Value - Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am generating a report but I hit a bit of a wall with a value that I need to pull from a report. I was trying to do a combination of a Vlookup and a Hlookup, but I can't get it to work.

So I need to pull the value that is 2 columns back to the **Signon** Value, and then reference that value acording to the value in the first column  **(1234569)**.

Any help is much apreciated

```
1234569 |   John    |   Smith   |   
        |           |           |   
From    |     To    |   Dur.    |   Activity
9:00    |   9:01    |   0:01    |   Open
9:01    |   9:14    |   0:13    |   Signon
```

Comment: Is your data always formatted the same?  Specifically, is '1234569' always 4 rows up and 3 columns to the left of 'Signon'?

Comment: no sometimes the "Signon" value is further down or viceversa

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like `=sign_off_time(1234569)` that returns `9:14`? That type of thing is pretty easy. But the exact implementation is going to depend greatly on where you want this data to read out, and what the rest of your sheet's structure is like.

Basically, the fundamental issue I think you're running into is that `VLOOKUP()` needs the index to be in the first column of the lookup array, and then can only find values to the right of the index. The solution is to use a combination of `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` instead of `VLOOKUP()`. [Here's a nice write up of how to use INDEX/MATCH and a comparison of this with VLOOKUP.](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)

EDIT: Ok, you ready? Here we go... if Sheet1 looks like this:

```
1234569 |John   Smith   

From    To  Dur.    Activity
9:00    9:01    0:01    Open
8:55    10:15   1:20    Activity3
6:55    8:19    1:24    Activity4
9:01    9:14    0:13    Signon

4657915 Jane    Doe 

From    To  Dur.    Activity
8:55    10:15   1:20    Open
6:55    16:33   9:38    Activity4
11:55   15:42   3:47    Signon

8461224 Bob Dulluth 
(etc)
```

Then this will work in Sheet2 (or anywhere, really). It finds the row of the lookup ID (e.g., 1234569), then finds the first occurrence of 'Signon' below that (no matter how far below), then looks up the second column from that row (sign off time). This **will** break if a person's record does not have a 'signon' activity, it'll find the 'signon' from the *next* person.

`=INDEX(Sheet1!C2,MATCH("Signon",INDIRECT("Sheet1!R"&TEXT(MATCH(Sheet2!RC1,Sheet1!C1,0),"@")&"C4:R"&TEXT(ROWS(C3),"@")&"C4",FALSE),0)+MATCH(Sheet2!RC1,Sheet1!C1,0)-1)`

The reference `Sheet2!RC1` in the formula is the lookup ID, so change as necessary.

Comment: The rest of the data is formated in a similar matter, But the value that I'm after is not always in the same row in relation to the value that I need to reference, but let me look at the link, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(Tested on Excel 2010)

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(INDEX($A:$D,MATCH($F$2,$A:$A,0),0),0,0,5,4),MATCH("Signon",$D:$D,0),MATCH("To",$3:$3,0))
```

Assumptions:

- List item number (1234569) is in Column A
- $F$2 contains the Record Number you wish to search for
- "Signon" is the 'Activity' row you're searching for and is found in column D
- "To" is the Column you're searching for.

  - The column titles in 3:3 stay the same throughout your sheet
- Each 'record' is 5 rows high by 4 columns wide

Going from here, you should be able to decipher the formula and adjust it as need be.  VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP are pretty limited...  It's usually better to take a little extra time to use INDEX/MATCH to locate data elsewhere in your sheet.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The bigger problem is that you are using lookup functions like MATCH INDEX, VLOOKUP with a report that is not in nice tabular data form.

If you have the ability to add some additional columns alongside the raw report, I'd recommend trying something like this:

[image]

The key is that you need some way to flag new 'records' in your raw report.  I took a guess that the only time 'From' appears in column A is to indicate a new record, but you may need a different formula to get the ID for column F.

Then your formula becomes a simple `=VLOOKUP("1234569Signon",$G:$H,2,false)`